# Typegoose v10 timestamps: true model option not creating `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties when creating an object

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, timestamp, typegoose

I'm trying to create a model for `User` and I want to add `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties automatically whenever an object is created or updated(this need to happen even if the object is created using MongoDB compass). I have tried:

1. Using `@modelOptions` decorator

   ```
   @modelOptions({
     schemaOptions: {
       timestamps: true,
       collection: COLLECTIONS.User,
     },
     options: {
       allowMixed: Severity.ALLOW,
     },
   })
   export class User {
     @prop({ type: () => String, required: true })
     name: string;
   }
   const UserModel = getModelForClass(User);

   export default UserModel;
   ```
2. Extexteding from `TimeStamps` class

   ```
    export class User extends TimeStamps {
    @prop({ type: () => String, required: true })
        name: string;
    }
    const UserModel = getModelForClass(User);

    export default UserModel;
   ```
3. and finally by,

   ```
    export class User {
      @prop({ type: () => String, required: true })
      name: string;
    }
    const UserModel = getModelForClass(User, schemaOptions: {
        timestamps: true,
        collection: COLLECTIONS.User,
      },
      options: {
        allowMixed: Severity.ALLOW,
      },);

    export default UserModel;
   ```

None of these methods worked. It creates the document in the user collection but the `createdAt`, `updatedAt` fields are not in the doc.
I'm using

- node v18.
- mongoose v6.11.5
- typegoose v10.4.0

Comment: "this need to happen even if the object is created using MongoDB compass", this will not work, because "timestamps" are a mongoose concept, not stored as something like a SQL Trigger

Comment: i just tested it locally with "mongoose@6.12.0" and "@typegoose/typegoose@10.4.0" and it works without problems, i dont know what your environment is but keep in mind that `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are only on the document once saved

Comment: Yeah, you're correct with the compass it does not create those properties and for the `seeding script` that I wrote the results are the same.  It works just fine with the queries triggered by the request. Did add timestamps to the seeding data. Cheers!